# C# Exception when creating a file when file name has spaces throws an error {"The given path's format is not supported."}

Tags: c#

Um trying to create a pdf file with the file name as follows

```
 Hello 1115 Apple Mango 27.08.2015 00:00:00.pdf
```

using

```
 var tempFileName = Fruit.Name + " " + numberName + " " + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString() + ".pdf";

 var pdfFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), tempFileName);
 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFile, Pdfcontent.GetBuffer());
```

Please note that my file name contain spaces, if I create a file name without spaces it will generate a file without any issues

Since it's containing spaces it throws an exception **{"The given path's format is not supported."}**

The Generated filepath looks something like this
**C:\Users\Sansa\AppData\Local\Temp\Hello 1115 Apple Mango 27.08.2015 00:00:00.pdf**

How to fix this issue

Comment: Assuming picking path/name that contains only supported characters is not an option you are out of luck (and spaces is not a problem).

Comment: It is the : that aren't supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in spaces. There are a few symbols, that deniend in naming: `<`, `>`, `:`, `"`, `/`,  `\`, `|`, `?`, `*`. Also you can check the rules for [naming files and folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247) on MSDN.

You can fix this issue by replacing this symbols to allowed. In your case you can use simple `replace`:

```
tempFileName = tempFileName.Replace(':', '_');    // prevent using : symbol
```

But much better is to get all unallowed symbols and use Regex to prevent using them:

```
var pattern = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
var r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(pattern)));
tempFileName = r.Replace(tempFileName, "_");
```

If you choose second variant, don't forget to add namespaces in your file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score 3):

`:` are not allowed in the file names. You could remove them.

Also you could replace spaces with the underscores `_` if you want.